# How to implement add sections of python code dynamically

Tags: python

I want to create a python file that uses a code stored in database

I have a table called CodeTable that has These data

```
ID    Code
-----------
1      import pymssql import pandas as pd import matplotlib.pyplot as plt import seaborn as sns import numpy as np  df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Projects\G.csv') plt.figure(figsize=(12, 9))

2      X = 1 + MasterKey
```

and in my code I have this

```
MasterKey = 7

#Some code to call Record with ID = 2 from DB
# a function to execute Python dynamically      <-------- I need this?!!

print(MasterKey) #<------------ Should return 8
```

Thanks

Comment: It can't really work as is because it's not valid python code. The way it is, it's not possible to parse the code since it's not properly separated with semicolons or newlines. Only line 2 would work

Comment: @Nakor Thanks for the comment, this is just an example and they all in one line coz of the question formatting, in the database each statement in different line.

Comment: Oh ok, then nevermind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) builtin function. For example, `exec("print('Hello World!')")`

Exec Documentation:

> This function supports dynamic execution of Python code. object must be either a string or a code object. If it is a string, the string is parsed as a suite of Python statements which is then executed (unless a syntax error occurs).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is pandas dataframe so we can using `eval`

```
pd.eval(df.loc[df.ID==2,'Code'].str.split('=').str[-1])[0]
8
```